# Custom spinner Android: Error inflating class mobileapps.android_app.assist.MyCustomSpinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to do a custom Spinner Class that I can just use it in the xml file of my android app.

Snippet of my Andrid app layout xml:

```
<mobileapps.android_app.assist.MyCustomSpinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/D3_Spinner_1"
            android:entries="@array/minutes"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
```

My custom spinner class:

```
package mobileapps.android_app.assist;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import mobileapps.android_app.R;
/**
 * Custom Spinner Class.
 * Erzeugt Typeface
 */
public class MyCustomSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner {
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = null;
    public MyCustomSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_item);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        this.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

The file R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

The file R.layout.spinner_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When I run this in the emulator I do get this error:

```
04-06 01:50:10.428 15550-15550/mobileapps.android_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: mobileapps.android_app, PID: 15550
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mobileapps.android_app/mobileapps.android_app.knowledgeCollectorActivities_2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class mobileapps.android_app.assist.MyCustomSpinner
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class mobileapps.android_app.assist.MyCustomSpinner
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class mobileapps.android_app.assist.MyCustomSpinner
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:618)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                        at mobileapps.android_app.knowledgeCollectorActivities_2.onCreate(knowledgeCollectorActivities_2.java:48)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Is there anyone who can help me out with this?
Thank you,
GPclips

Comment: To allow your custom `View` to be inflated from a layout, you need a public constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`.

Comment: Hey sir, thank you for that! :-)